# Grails cannot save object

Tags: hibernate, grails

Im getting a rather strange error trying to save objects to my database. The code has worked perfeclty when trying to save the base class objects but now I am trying to save a domain class that inherits from the base domain class.

Here is the parent class:

```
package com.twc.fatcaone

class Record {

long batchID

}
```

and the child class that I am trying to save:

```
package com.twc.fatcaone

class AccountRecord extends Record {

    long uniqueId
    String accountId
    String type
    String insurance
    String currencyType
    float amount
    String upSerDel
    String generalComments

    static mapping = {
        collection "accountRecords"
        database "twcdb"
}
}
```

The code in my service that's trying to do the save:

```
accountRecordList.each { 

                def accountRecord = new AccountRecord(batchID: params.selectedBatch.id,
                                                        uniqueId: it.uniqueId,
                                                        accountId: it.accountId,
                                                        type: it.type,
                                                        insurance: it.insurance,
                                                        currencyType: it.currencyType,
                                                        amount: it.amount,
                                                        upSerDel: it.upSerDel,
                                                        generalComments: it.generalComments)

                       if (!AccountRecord.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
                           println "ERROR: Record could not be saved!"
                           def errorValue = AccountRecord.errors
                           println errorValue
                       }
```

and the error I get when trying to do the save:

`/FatcaOne_0/customer/upload - parameters:
dataTypegrp: 1
fileTypegrp: 1
No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.AccountRecord.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:true, failOnError:true]]
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.AccountRecord.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:true, failOnError:true]]
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map)
    Line | Method
->>   91 | methodMissing               in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi`
`- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     32 | call                        in org.grails.datastore.gorm.internal.StaticMethodInvokingClosure
|     65 | doCall . . . . . . . . . .  in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$_$tt__excelAccountFileUpload_closure4
|     53 | $tt__excelAccountFileUpload in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService
|    119 | upload . . . . . . . . . .  in com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController
|    198 | doFilter                    in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                         in java.lang.Thread
/FatcaOne_0/customer/upload - parameters:
dataTypegrp: 1
fileTypegrp: 1
No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.AccountRecord.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:true, failOnError:true]]
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: com.twc.fatcaone.AccountRecord.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:true, failOnError:true]]
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map)
    Line | Method
->>   91 | methodMissing               in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi`
`- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     32 | call                        in org.grails.datastore.gorm.internal.StaticMethodInvokingClosure
|     65 | doCall . . . . . . . . . .  in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService$_$tt__excelAccountFileUpload_closure4
|     53 | $tt__excelAccountFileUpload in com.twc.fatcaone.FileImportService
|    119 | upload . . . . . . . . . .  in com.twc.fatcaone.CustomerController
|    198 | doFilter                    in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                         in java.lang.Thread`

Comment: Is the new class still in the /domain/ directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't that be a lowercase 'a' in the word AccountRecord just before the call to the save function?

Comment: That is correct.  The call to `AccountRecord.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` is being treated as a static method call on the `AccountRecord` class.  It should be invoked ad an instance method on the `accountRecord` variable.

Comment: Thanks so much. Wow, I guess I got cross eyes staring at code too long. Time for a break!